# Dropdown menu on SVG won't work with viewBox attribute

Tags: html, svg

I would like to set inside the SVG a dropdown menu using foreignObject. But it won't work how it should when I set the viewBox SVG attribute. I have been trying on Firefox 17.0.1. 
I remade the problem to reproduce the error in a simple code below. Anyone knows how to fix it ?

When you click on the dropdown menu the list doesn't appear right below, it appears in a different position and you can't click on it.

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svgScimul" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 1200 600" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g>
    <foreignObject class="node" x="100" y="40" width="200" height="200">
          <select>
            <option value="1">Test1</option>
            <option value="2">Aga</option>
            <option value="2">BBB</option>
            <option value="4">AAA</option>
          </select>
    </foreignObject>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Report it to bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&Component=SVG

Comment: [Logged it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=824464)

Comment: thank you for the log robertc!